# How to live LocalHost on Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, localhost, vnc-server

Does anyone know how I can live my app on localhost to access the link from any devices.

Please Guide?

I have tried using Ngrok. Ngink, localxpose and it Failed

Comment: This is not a good question, Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for future questions, And for now, We need to know what have you tried, Ngrok works fine.

Comment: Here is what I needed to do on this link https://datawookie.dev/blog/2021/08/websockify-novnc-behind-an-nginx-proxy/